# Is there a tool that provides on-the-fly code coverage for a Maven project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, code-coverage

Is such a thing possible?

To explain: I'm on a project where the Acceptance Tests are being run in a bespoke way from an actual webpage rather than as part of one of Maven's test phases. *It's a long story why so please consider criticisms of this to be off-topic!*

Would like to see the coverage after clicking a button that runs the tests. On-the-fly coverage while the tests are running isn't a necessity but would at least like to be able to see the line-by-line Java code coverage in Eclipse after the tests have finished - ideally with the page still up and JVM still running.

Would be grateful if any replies could include any needed tools, pom fragments and setup information.

EDIT: Forgot to mention the customer is only interested in using open source tools.

Comment: From your tags: which coverage tool do you want to use, emma or cobertura? Could you clarify what the order of actions should be?

Comment: I put those tags on as I thought they might direct people with knowledge to the question. Actually, I've tried using EclEmma with the emma-maven-plugin but couldn't get any coverage to show up. Might be something I'm doing wrong though (e.g. the execution phase/goal). Haven't tried cobertura yet but it looks similar. The order of actions is: (1) Deploy the application (2) Open "test" webpage (3) Click on button to run all tests (4) <<<Would like to see the coverage from the above - ideally in Eclipse if that's possible>>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and easy. Our (Semantic Designs) Java Test Coverage tools do this just fine.

You instrument the application and compile it.   As it runs (anything: units tests, ad hoc interactive exercises, etc.) it collects test coverage data.  At any moment, you can cause the test coverage data to be dumped without disturbing the application.  That dump coverage data can be immediately imported and viewed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply - this is useful to know for the future but unfortunately on this project the customer is only interested in using open source tools. Wondering if you might be able to confirm whether such a thing definitely isn't possible in Emma, Cobertura etc?

Comment: If they can do it, I'd expect the process to be similar.  I have no experience with those tools.